# Is it possible to style a span as a tooltip using css

Tags: html, css

I have some html that is returned when I submit a form that I can't change.

```
<div>
   <label>Enter your email</div>
   <input type="text" name="email" value="bademail@" />
   <div class="error">That email is not valid</div>
<div>
```

I'd like to style it so that the div.error shows an icon which when I hover over shows the text as a tooltip.

Can this be done using css alone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a hover on a div, to display the child span:

```css
.error {
  position: relative;
}

.error > span {
  display: none;
}

.error:hover > span {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
  bottom: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 5px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div>
   <label>Enter your email</label>
   <input type="text" name="email" value="bademail@" />
   <div class="error">icon<span>That email is not valid</span></div>
</div>
```

You can also use a pseudo elements instead of the span:

```css
.error {
  position: relative;
}
.error:hover::before {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
  bottom: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 5px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  color: white;
  content: attr(data-tooltip);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label>Enter your email</label>
  <input type="text" name="email" value="bademail@" />
  <div class="error" data-tooltip="That email is not valid">icon</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works great. I can't change the html (without using JS which is not preferred) so instead I've used a background image to show my icon.

Comment: I'm glad you like it :)